# Programmatically get properties of UserControl.Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a simple WPF test program, based on what Visual Studio gives me when I add a UserControl1.xaml to my project. In XAML it appears that the blank "background canvas" is of type Grid.

When I create an instance of UserControl1, is there any possibility to programmatically access the underlying Grid instance (so I can change the background color)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the grid a name:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="YourFancyGrid">
          <!-- Grid stuff -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then you can access it from the C# side:

```
YourFancyGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since UserControl is a ContentControl the grid is in the Content property.